# QT cannot find connected low energy bluetooth device on macos

Tags: macos, qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm running qt 5.10.1 bluetooth low energy scanner example on my mac mini(macos 10.15),  the scanner can not discover connected BTLE device(not in the list of all discovered Bluetooth device), but works fine when the device is not connected to the system.

```
discoveryAgent = new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent();
discoveryAgent->setLowEnergyDiscoveryTimeout(5000);
connect(discoveryAgent, &QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::deviceDiscovered,
      this, &Device::addDevice);
connect(discoveryAgent, 
QOverload<QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::Error>::of(&QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::error),
      this, &Device::deviceScanError);
connect(discoveryAgent, &QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::finished, this, &Device::deviceScanFinished);
discoveryAgent->start(QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::LowEnergyMethod);
```

I don't know why and how can I get a already connected BLE device? I would appreciate for any help.